# How to show continuity of $\cdot$ in a normed vector space?

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $(V,+,\cdot)$ be a normed vector space with the underlying field $K$ .

We have to show that $+,\cdot$ are continuous functions. Since $V$  becomes a metric space under this norm so I can use sequential criteria of continuity to show it.

I have proved it for $+$ .

I have taken sequences $(x_n,y_n)\in V\times V$.Now $||x_n+y_n-(x+y)||\leq ||x_n-x||+||y_n-y||\to 0 $ as $n\to \infty $

However I cant use the sequential criteria of continuity in case of $\cdot :K\times V\to V$ because $K\times V$ is not a metric space .

How to show it here?

Comment: $K$ should have a metric on it, otherwise what's the topology on $K$?

Comment: take a convergent sequence $a_n$ in $K$ and a convergent sequence $x_n$ in $V$ and show that $a_n x_n$ converges. Hint: both sequence are bounded.

Comment: yes I understand how to prove it ;but it's not clear why is it correct @user251257;what is meant by   a natural norm

Comment: $K$ is a field ;how to get topology here  @QuangHoang; but it is written in the Wikipedia page that $.$ is continuous...Why?

Comment: There is a norm on $K$: in the axiom you have something like $\| \alpha x\| = |\alpha|\cdot \| x\|$.

Comment: yes, $K$ should have a norm or absolute value.  otherwise how could you define norm on $V$?

Comment: Coming at @QuangHoang's question from another angle:  What's your definition of continuous function on $K$?  I assume you can show continuity for multiplication for a fixed element of $K$, so progress depends on whatever continuity means with respect to small displacements in $K$.